# how to disable chrome cache when use chunked response

Tags: php, flush, chunked

`<?php`
`echo 'first<br>';`
`ob_flush();`
`flush();`
`file_get_contents("http://ttt.tt");`
`echo "second";`

http://ttt.tt is not reachable. so in browser we can see the output "first" and then wait for "30s"/*Maximum execution time of each script*/ there will output "second".
in IE、FF, it works ok.
but in chrome,"first" && "second" will output together.

my english is bad.i Don't know if you understand.help!!!

i also tried to disable browser's cache like this:
`header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");`
`header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);`
`header("Pragma: no-cache");`

but problems still exist..

Comment: Configure your web server with no caching.

Comment: @webbandit Header Set **? same to header(); set chache expired time?

Comment: what web server do you have? Apache?

Comment: @webbandit yes,Is configure webserver header sets same to function header in script?

Comment: To tun off caching in Apache put `ExpiresActive Off` in `httpd.conf` file - in the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to disable cache. It's all about content type encoding. What I simply did was:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Initially it was:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html');
```

... which didn't work. Specifying "**charset=UTF-8**" immediately forced Chrome to render chunked responses.

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be that "Pragma: no-cache" won`t work every time. The HTTP specification does not set any guidelines for Pragma response headers. Try to use "Expires".

If you need additional info, here is the [link to web caching tutorial](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`.

See [Chunked transfer encoding - browser behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56089065/277267) for a thorough explanation.