# Chunked transfer in chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome

according to [Chunked transfer encoding - browser behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557900/chunked-transfer-encoding-browser-behavior/24456148#24456148)

```
set_time_limit(0);

header('Content-Encoding: chunked');
header('Transfer-Encoding: chunked');
header('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8');
header('Connection: keep-alive');

echo str_pad('', 1024, ' ');

while (true) {
// do some echo 
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

hi guys, any problem with my code? it is not work in chrome. work good in curl & safari.

Comment: You'd do well to look over this post and try to make your meaning a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

this works.

```
set_time_limit(0);

header('Content-Encoding: chunked');
header('Transfer-Encoding: chunked');
header('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8');
header('Connection: keep-alive');

while (true) {
    echo str_pad('', 1024, ' ');// browser/nginx/fastcgi max buffer size
    // do some echo

    // ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```