# Disabling Chrome buffering when streaming text data

Tags: google-chrome, http, streaming

We have a site that streams text data over http. It is set up in the following way:

- It doesn't do any server side buffering
- `Content-Type` is `text/plain`
- `Transfer-Encoding` is `chunked`
- Compression is disabled

When using plain `curl` or FireFox, the text gets streamed to the browser to the browser from the first byte. But when using Chrome, no text is displayed until 1024 bytes have been sent. After that, everything show up instantly.

**Question**: is there a way to disable this buffering behavior?

More info: here is a simple ASP.NET page that demonstrates the behavior:

```
<%@ language=c# %>

<%
    Response.BufferOutput = false;
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

    for (int i=0; i<50; i++)
    {
        Response.Write("01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567\r\n");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
%>
```

With a web.config that disables compression:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I also have a live repro running at http://bufferingtest.azurewebsites.net/. Just hit it from both Chrome and FireFox to observe the different behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` to your headers and let me know how it goes for you.

According to [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options):

> The `X-Content-Type-Options` response HTTP header is a marker used by
>   the server to indicate that the MIME types advertised in the
>   `Content-Type` headers should not be changed and be followed. This
>   allows to opt-out of MIME type sniffing, or, in other words, it is a
>   way to say that the webmasters knew what they were doing.

Comment: See [Chunked transfer encoding - browser behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56089065/277267)

Answer (score 4):

Try switching your `Content-Type` from `text/plain` to `application/octet-stream`.

Check this out, for further reading:

[Do I need Content-Type: application/octet-stream for file download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508788/do-i-need-content-type-application-octet-stream-for-file-download)

This fix worked perfectly for me. I had the same issue you're describing, where sending small text chunks encoded as `text/plain; charset=UTF-8` caused a delay in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Changing the type to application/octet resolved the issue on Chrome without effecting FireFox performance.

Comment: text/event-stream works, and allows you to preview the response in Chrome without it trying to download. Not sure if that is a real mime type or not but I've seen it used.

Comment: `octet-stream` makes the browser download the data into a file. `event-stream` works like a charm.